# How to initiate local loopback test in Windows for each port?

Tags: ethernet

I want to create a local loopback test for a quad-port ethernet controller in c#. I have seen the solution for Linux but not for Windows. Need some pointers on how to start with this for example, do I need port address or port id or MAC address..I mean how will I know that loopback is running for which port out of 4 ports.

Then I assume once port number/id is mentioned I have to go to particular offset to read the value so that I can enable local/internal loopback by enabling a particular bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardware specific. While Linux has got tools that work with various NICs, Windows doesn't.

You either need to adapt your code to each driver (probably only vendor- not device-specific) or deactivate the driver and bang the hardware directly.